# undefined method `first' Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 2 models:

**board.rb**

```
class Board
 has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, :autosave => true
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post
 has_and_belongs_to_many :boards
end
```

In my **posts_controller.rb**

```
def create
 @post = current_user.posts.new(params[:post])
 @post.save
end
```

In my view posts I have a form with collection_select field:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<%= f.collection_select :board_ids, Board.where(:user_id => current_user.id), :id, :name%>
<% end %>
```

I get with type relation **has_and_belongs_to_many** the next error:

**undefined method `first' for BSON::ObjectId('4f2e61ce1d41c8412a000215'):BSON::ObjectId**

:board_ids is an array type **board_ids: []** in object Post.

**How save the object from field collection_select in this array?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you are using a drop down list to map to a multi-valued field (board_ids). So your application is trying to set the board_ids field to a single value (a BSON::ObjectId) when mongoid is expecting an array.

If a Post can be associated with many Boards (and assuming you don't have a very large number of boards for a given user) then perhaps a better way to get this working is to use a set of checkboxes rather than a single drop down list.

```
<% Board.where(:user_id => current_user.id).each do |board| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'post[board_ids][]', board.id, @post.board_ids.include?(board.id) %>
  <%= board.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks steve. Thats works but I need select field :D Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a select you need to specify the html option "multiple" in order to submit an array of options.

```
<select multiple="muliple"> ...
```

My working Rails form (using simple_form) looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @exercise, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
   <%= f.input_field :category_ids, :multiple => "multiple", :as => :grouped_select, :collection => CategoryGroup.all, :group_method => :categories %>
<% end %>
```